# Cannot get rid of a bizarre 2px space between my child image and parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have tried everything I know. I'm beginning to think it's being created by Tumblrs javascript.
First, I do have inline blocks, which i know read white space and add pixels. But after much testing, stripping all my javascript, and removing everything and leaving just a standard

```
<div><img src="image"/></div>
```

I still get this 2px space below the image!

So I'm wondering is there a way to do this without jquery perhaps?

```
.parentdiv {
    height:100% - 2px;
}
```

?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This issue is caused by the line-height, because text is expected, too.

### Solution

```
line-height: 0;
```

### Sample

http://jsfiddle.net/YGjpk/

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that wouldn’t modify the entire container line-height is to make images behave as a block element. Because they are inline by default.

```
img {
  display: block;
}
```

Yeah, I know, it’s old, but always good to know I think.